# Filter or sort collapsed results in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running a price comparing website and I have an Elasticsearch index containing documents that have the current price for a product at a certain store. So, there are multiple documents for a single product.

Now, I would like to get the products where the cheapest price has the highest discount percentage. I have tried the following using collapse, but this returns me the products that have the highest discount percentage on any of their prices, not necessarily the cheapest.

```json
{
  "collapse": {
    "field": "product_id"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "discount_pct": {
              "gt": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 12,
  "sort": [
    {
      "discount_pct": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

An ideal outcome would be to get the document with the lowest `price` for each product and then sort these results by `discount_pct` descending.

Is there a way to do what I am trying?
I have tried other things like adding inner results that are sorted a second time, but that didn't go so well.

Comment: Could you give us some sample documents ?

Comment: Can you show the index mapping please?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

Partial success, my solution does not allow to ultimately sort by `discount_pct`. Although you do have the lowest `price` and the highest `discount_pct` per `product_id`

## Solution

Instead of using `collapse` and `sort`. I am going to use the [aggregations feature of Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html).

I will first of all create buckets by `product_id`, to be able to compare at the next stage the values per product.
To do so I use a [Term aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

Then I use the [top_hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html), which allow me to provide a custom sorting rule. Sorting first by price to get the cheapest, then by `discount` in case of a tie.

The query below:

```json
GET /72519852/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_product": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product_id.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_price": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "price": {
                  "order": "asc"
                }
              },
              {
                "discount": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to get the 3 `product_id` I have, with the lowest `price` then the highest `discount`

But I was not able to sort the order of the buckets.

```json
{
  ...
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "by_product" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "aaa",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "by_price" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "72519852",
                  "_id" : "4KNDToEBOgujegeQwGfa",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "product_id" : "aaa",
                    "price" : 20,
                    "discount" : 20
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    20,
                    20
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "bbb",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "by_price" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "72519852",
                  "_id" : "4qNDToEBOgujegeQwGfa",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "product_id" : "bbb",
                    "price" : 20,
                    "discount" : 22
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    20,
                    22
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "ccc",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "by_price" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "72519852",
                  "_id" : "5KNDToEBOgujegeQwGfa",
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "product_id" : "ccc",
                    "price" : 20,
                    "discount" : 21
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    20,
                    21
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

## To Reproduce

```json
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"72519852"}}
{"product_id":"aaa","price":20,"discount":20}
{"index":{"_index":"72519852"}}
{"product_id":"aaa","price":20,"discount":1}
{"index":{"_index":"72519852"}}
{"product_id":"bbb","price":20,"discount":22}
{"index":{"_index":"72519852"}}
{"product_id":"bbb","price":20,"discount":1}
{"index":{"_index":"72519852"}}
{"product_id":"ccc","price":20,"discount":21}

GET /72519852/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_product": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "product_id.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_price": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "price": {
                  "order": "asc"
                }
              },
              {
                "discount": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some means of runtime field / calculated field. suppose you have:

**Store A**: sells the same product **$200** and has **55%** discount so discounted price is **$90**

**Store B**: sells same product **$100** with **12%** discount and discounted price is **$88**

**Store C**: sells same product **$87** with **0%** discount and discounted price is **$87**

Which of these stores sells the product with highest discount and lowest price? By using raw field values for this kind of sorting you would be in conflict.

In my opinion you should have a calculated field that gives a balance between price and discount and therefore sorting is done based on this calculated field.

One solution is using a **weighted price** in sorting, for example price that has a weight based on cheapest price of product among all stores and generating a calculated price for each store then sorting based on some calculation on this price and store's discount.

[Runtime fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime.html)

[Elasticsearch Runtime Fields – How to Use Runtime Fields in Elasticsearch](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/how-tos/runtime-fields/)

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked many times.
The sort keyword takes in an array that can target multiple fields.

You can leverage this behaviour for your usecase by simply sorting first by price ascending and then by discount in descending order:

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search 
{
  "sort" : [
    { "price" : {"order" : "asc"}},
    { "discount_pct" : "desc" }
  ],
"query" : {
    ...
}}
```